# XDocument xml parsed but fails to save attributes. Xml.Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I am looping over the controls and setting the textbox values in the xml like so:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

/* code */

XDocument _xml = XDocument.Load(_DialogOpen);

foreach (Control t in tableLayoutPanel.Controls)
{
    if (t is TextBox)
    {
        //setting the value
        _xml.Root.SetAttributeValue("isPreview", t.Text);
        //log
        textBox.AppendText("n=" + t.Name + " t=" + t.Text + Environment.NewLine);           
    }
}

_xml.Save(_DialogOpen);
```

My problem is that the `_xml.Save(_DialogOpen);` does save but none of the attributes are changed and there is no exception. If anyone has any suggestions it will be greatly appreciated.

xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config id="1">
  <parmVer __id="0" version="V1234" />
    <RecordSetChNo __id="0" isPreview="1" AIVolume="15" />
    <RecordSetChNo __id="1" isPreview="1" AIVolume="15" />
    <RecordSetChNo __id="2" isPreview="1" AIVolume="15" />
    <RecordSetChNo __id="3" isPreview="1" AIVolume="15" />
    <RecordSetChNo __id="4" isPreview="1" AIVolume="15" />
    <RecordSetChNo __id="5" isPreview="1" AIVolume="15" />
    <RecordSetChNo __id="6" isPreview="1" AIVolume="15" />
    <RecordSetChNo __id="7" isPreview="1" AIVolume="15" />
</config>
```

Comment: Maybe [OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8) is what you want instead?

Comment: I'm assuming _DialogOpen is a string with a file name?  Have you debugged it to see for sure that it's getting into the if statement?  Also, if you don't need all the functionality of XDocument, you should use XElement.

Comment: @zx485 yes I use  `OpenFileDialog` to get the file path. I see now the file is saved but the attributes are not saved. see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the following line from OP

```
_xml.Root.SetAttributeValue("isPreview", t.Text);
```

The above code is attempting to set the attribute in Root element, when it looks like you want to set it for the Element `RecordSetChNo`.

Also, believe you want to set the attribute based on each of the textboxes, ie, each textbox has a corresponding attribute in the xml. In such a scenario, you would need to filter the right XElement (since there are more than one `RecordSetChNo`) before setting the attribute.

```
    foreach (Control t in tableLayoutPanel.Controls)
    {
        if (t is TextBox)
        {
            //filter the xelement, only a sample here. 
            // Should change according to your requirement
            var filteredXElement = _xml.Root
                                      .Descendants("RecordSetChNo")
                                      .First(x=>x.Attribute("__id").Value==idToFilter);
            // Now set the attribute for the filtered Element
            filteredXElement.SetAttributeValue("isPreview", t.Text);
            //log
            textBox.AppendText("n=" + t.Name + " t=" + t.Text + Environment.NewLine);           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks yes this allows me to save, I use the tag property to hold the value of the `idToFilter` like this :`_IsPreview.Tag = __id;`. It seems to be running fine for now.